# phpinfo() showing different upload_max_filesize than in php.ini

Tags: php, apache

I am getting a different value for `upload_max_filesize` from `php.ini` file and `phpinfo()`.

While on `php.ini` I have setup 128M for it, on `phpinfo()` it is showing me 2M.
I have tried restart the `apache` and add a new `php.ini` to another folder and point to it using VHost but that didn't solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that there was an error on `php.ini` at line 180, so every value after that turns to default. And as `upload_max_filesize` was after that, it have turn to default value of 2M.

I could discover that by typing `php -i` on the command line, and even though it have rendered all php settings, the first line was an error, so you can check there where is the error on your `php.ini`. It also tells you which line the error is.

Hope it can help someone else!